# Does PlainText transmit data securely?

Tags: security, 3rd-party

Does the iPhone App [PlainText](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/plaintext-dropbox-text-editing/id391254385?mt=8) transmit data securely (i.e. does it use SSL?), or it there a risk of my data being read by third parties when I sync with dropbox?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I emailed the company, and according to them:

> PlainText syncs using the provided Dropbox SDK, which specifies
>   SSL/https

... meaning that everything is transmitted securely.

Answer (score 3):

On dropbox's web site, it says:
[All transmission of file data and metadata occurs over an encrypted channel (SSL)](http://www.dropbox.com/help/27).

Furthermore, data send over the 3G cellular connection uses a 3G over-the-air encryption protocol (which will likely be unencrypted for forwarding to the internet past the cell tower).

Comment: Dropbox may be encrypting the data over SSL - don't know if PlainText talks directly to the Dropbox site or proxies the connection through some over place first as PlainText is not the same developer as Dropbox.

Comment: @Rex: that is exactly the same concern I have.